# Set Argument to Service

Tags: symfony

Symfony 2.8

Having a service factory, I want to pass a simple 'string' argument when call/invoke/get (however you say it) the service.

```
    <services>
    <service id="service.builder_factory" class="Domain\Bundle\Services\ServiceBuilder">
           <argument name="optional" type="string"/>
           <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
           <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
           <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
           <argument key="dir">%kernel.logs_dir%</argument>
       </service>

       <service id="reports" class="Domain\Bundle\Services\ReportsService">
           <factory service="service.builder_factory" method="__factoryMethod"/>
           <tag name="service.builder"/>
       </service>
    </services>
```

And I don't know how to set that string as a parameter.

```
$this->getContainer()->get('reports')->setParameter('optional', 'string_to_pass');
```

Service factory works, but I need to pass a parameter from controller or command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a parameter to a service you got from the service container. It have been instantiated already. Factory service in Symfony configuration will not help you in this case too.

You can use [Prototype](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype/php) pattern for example: get your "not configured" service from a container, clone and configure it:

```
class MyService {
    private $reportPrototype;

    public function __construct(Report $reportPrototype) // your 'report' service
    {
        $this->reportPrototype = $reportPrototype;
    }

    public function someMethod() {
        $report = $this->getReport('optional');
    }

    protected function getReport(string $optional)
    {
        $result = clone $this->reportPrototype;
        $result->setOptional($optional); // configure your service
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

`services.xml`:

```
<services>
    <service id="reports" class="Domain\Bundle\Services\ReportsService">
        <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
        <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
        <argument key="dir">%kernel.logs_dir%</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="my_service" class="MyService">
        <argument type="service" id="reports"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry! Thanks for your answer. Could you complement your answer with the service.xml structure, dependencyInjection configuration and how to invoke the service, please? I don't know how to fit your solution.

Comment: I guess I should follow this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/autowiring.html

Comment: I updated my answer. You do not need service factory anymore. Just remove your `optional` argument from `reports` service constructor and everything should work.